# Getting the Item Count of a large sharepoint list in fastest way

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am trying to get the count of the items in a sharepoint document library programatically. The scale I am working with is 30-70000 items. We have usercontrol in a smartpart to display the count . Ours is a TEAM site.

This is the code to get the total count:

```
            SPList VoulnterrList = web.Lists[ListTitle];

            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

            query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
            string queries = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ApprovalStatus' /><Value Type='Choice'>Pending</Value></Eq></Where>";
            query.Query = queries;
            SPListItemCollection lstitemcollAssoID = VoulnterrList.GetItems(query);
            lblCount.Text = "Total Proofs: " + VoulnterrList.Items.Count.ToString() + " Pending Proofs: " + lstitemcollAssoID.Count.ToString();
```

The problem is this has serious performance issue it takes 75 to 80 sec to load the page. if we comment this page load will decrees to 4 sec. Any better approch for this problem

Ours is sharepoint 2007

Answer (score 3):

Use `VoulnterrList.ItemCount` instead of `VoulnterrList.Items.Count`.

When List.Items is used, all items in the list are loaded from the content database.  Since we don't actually need the items to get the count this is wasted overhead.

This will fix performance at line 8, but you may still have issues at line 9 depending on the number of results returned by the query.

Comment: yes we have the same scenario we have some 600 items in the query result but 62000 items are there in the list

Comment: @sooraj: Does that mean you're still having problems?

Comment: no no i will implement it , i was responing to ur previous comment.

Comment: we need to do both right ? use ItemCounts and Restirct the columns using <ViewFields>

Comment: @sooraj: As best practice, yes, but whether you 'need' to do it depends on how the system is performing after the first improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two optimizations here:

- Create an index on one of the column of your list
- Use that column in `<ViewFields>` section of your CAML query so that only that indexed column is retrieved.

This should speed up. See this article on how to create index on column:
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=162